# Azure function app - output CosmosDB

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

Im using Python, and there is no documentation on doing this in Python. I have blob storage working with python. Now I am trying to save data to the cosmos db. I have no idea what i am supposed to do in azure function?

> cosmosdb_data = open(os.environ['outputDocument'], 'wb')

Would really appreciate any help on this!

EDIT:

I got it storing, but it complains that the document is corrupt anmd the _id field is missing. Does this mean you have to set your own id??

```
data = {
    "timestamp": datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
    "image":"path/image.jpg",
    "device":subject.split(",")[1],
    "detected":"false",
    "detection_type":"null"
}

document = open(os.environ['outputCosmosDB'], 'w')
document.write('%s' % data)
document.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` doesn't output valid JSON, does it? Doesn't it output single quotes, not double quotes? You need to make sure it outputs valid JSON.

_id is not necessary.

Also, Python on Azure Functions v1 is not very good and I'd recommend not using it. We're actively working on a new version of Python for v2 which will work properly for this kind of thing.

Comment: I hope it comes soon! Let memake sure about the quotes, your probably right. I just dont know what it expects from me

Comment: It wants double quotes. When I tried your sample, the output file was single quotes, so I think that's likely the problem.

Comment: Even when its output with double quotes, as valid JSON, it gives the same error. so i make data a python dict. then document.write(json.dumps(data))

Comment: when you do output the data as a json string, it doesn't work? Could you update your question with the current code and output?